# Modify the date a file has been changed with php

Tags: php, file, time

I'm testing a cache code in php that is based in filemtime. When a file is modified, if filemtime returns a unix time lesser than the max unix time for cache, then a query is repeated.

Problem is my tests must introduce the time factor making them 2 seconds slow. I want to reduce that time by modifying the date/time for the file so I can have control about when a file cache has expired without having to sleep n seconds.

Anyone has an idea about how can I do this?

Regards

Comment: You can use `touch()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php

Comment: Thanks, I've realized there is in fact a parameter where you can pass the mtime to the touch command so it generates the file with the given unix time. Now my tests will run faster! :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, PHP's `touch()` function can change the modification time of a file. Example:

```
$mtime = time() - 3600;
touch($filename, $mtime);
```

This will change the modification time to one hour in the past.

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php